# See Questions that already up voted and now has accepted answer

Tags: support

In many situation i faced questions that deserved to vote up, But not accepted answer confirmed still now. So i close question window and go away!

Some time later i want to see questions that already up voted and now accepted answer confirmed and i never seen accepted answer until now!

Is there any way to see this kind of question with query or something else? Or adding this feature can help to improve usability?

Comment: So you want to review questions you have seen before? Sorry, your question is unclear to me.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Have seen before but that's time not answer accepted confirmed, Later when i login i want to see questions that before up voted and now have accepted answer(to see what is answer of question that is attractive for me before), Sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 4):

The only way available now to do this is to mark the question as favorite. You will see updated on that post under your own profile.

You can go over that list and check all posts that have the accepted color marking on the answer count.